# Multi dimensional array to hash

Tags: php, arrays, hash, multidimensional-array

```
Array 
[1] => Array ( [0] => x [1] => num1 [2] => num2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => y [1] => num3 [2] => num4 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => z [1] => num5 [2] => num6 ) 
..........
```

What I want in php is, [0] index values i.e. x,y,z... become the index and num1, num2... become their values. In short I wanted a hash which has x,y,z... as indexes and num1, num2(for x) num3,num4(for y) as values for those indexes. which should look like,

```
Array 
[x] => Array ( [0] => num1 [1] => num2 ) 
[y] => Array ( [0] => num3 [1] => num4 ) 
[z] => Array ( [0] => num5 [1] => num6 )
```

Answer (score 3):

So something like:

```
$new = Array();
foreach($original as $entry) $new[array_shift($entry)] = $entry;
```

(Untested, may be buggy with order of operations, but probably fine).

Comment: thanks a lot..Its working fine. I am learning programming and php. You guys are really helpful. Thanks again.